# Convert Base64 encoded string to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, utf-8

I have Base64 string that represents a PDF file which needs to be converted to a PDF file, and open with the default PDF reader or browser in C#.

I have written only the part of Base64 string because it's too long string to paste here.

```
public void DownloadPDF()
{
    string pdflocation = "E:\\";
    string fileName = "softcore.pdf";
    // This is only part of Base64 string
    var base64String = "JVBERi0xLjQKJdP0zOEKMSAwIue704O58dOXPgst+hmQ+laj/"; 
    int mod4 = base64String.Length % 4;
    if (mod4 > 0)
    {
        base64String += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
    }
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);        

    if (Directory.Exists(pdflocation))
    {
        pdflocation = pdflocation + fileName;
        using (MemoryStream Writer = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", data.Length.ToString());
            Writer.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            //Writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }                
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that it shows as pdf generating but at the end, it says Network error.

The decoded string from the input encoded Base64 string:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code as *text* rather than as an image - and also to tell us what's going wrong at the moment. You've shown some code, but not told us what problem you're facing.

Comment: @DaisyShipton The problem is that it shows as pdf generating but at the end it says Network error.

Comment: Please put that information into your question then (with more detail - *what* says "network error"?) and edit your question to include the code as text. As an aside, your catch block *just* loses information... I'd strongly suggest removing the try/catch entirely.

Comment: @DaisyShipton: I haven't pasted the code because Base64 string is too long to paste here.

Comment: So show a shorter string, with a comment that you'd actually be getting it from somewhere else. (I assume you don't really have it hard-coded into your production code.) Showing an image of the code instead is not the best solution to that problem.

Comment: @DaisyShipton: Code is pasted here.

Comment: can you retry after removing the `mod4 > 0` part and replacing your using statement with `using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create(pdflocation))
{

    stream.Write(data , 0, data .Length);
}`

Comment: Your binary seems fine as after decoding it starts from `%PDF-1.4` but there can be some issue with this too, try posting your compete base64 string here

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to paste the entire base64 string as it says too long by 43079 characters

Comment: @SamyuktaR. try the code I posted above and use CodePen or some online fiddle to share the code when there is a problem related to that

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil. Okay thanks for your help, I will try and let you know.

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil. I got this error with your implemented code.
Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

Comment: `int mod4 = base64String.Length % 4;
if (mod4 > 0 )
{
    base64String += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
}` put this code back

Comment: or you can try this too `byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptedtext);`

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil. I tried with all attempts with your provided code but no luck so far.

Comment: then the problem is with your base64 string, please try to  verify after decoding your base 64 string to pdf here: https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html

Comment: I think the base64 string is valid because it generates the decoded string. I tried from both https://www.base64decode.org/ and https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html

Comment: @SamyuktaR. instead of only decoding it, try Decode and Download

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil.  Yes exactly that is what I am trying to do. I tried with various code approaches but none of them works. Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: @SamyuktaR. did you try to download the file from the freeformatter.com? you need to click `Decode and Download`

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil. Yes I did but it says failed to load the PDF document.

Comment: @SamyuktaR. that means there is a problem with your PDF document or more precisely your base64 string is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine if a PDF is converted base 64 from some online platform like **freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html** and use that base 64 string in the code below:

```
                 string pdflocation = "D:\\";
                  string fileName = "softcore.pdf";

                  // put your base64 string converted from online platform here instead of V
                  var base64String = V;

                  int mod4 = base64String.Length % 4;

                  // as of my research this mod4 will be greater than 0 if the base 64 string is corrupted
                  if (mod4 > 0)
                  {
                        base64String += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
                  }
                  pdflocation = pdflocation + fileName;

                  byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

                  using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create(pdflocation))
                  {
                        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                  }
```

This should save the PDF file in `D:\\` ,  again the problem is in your base 64 encoded string

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes  I think the base64 string might be corrupted one. I need to confirm with the client. Anyways thanks for the response.